# Must open string endpoints lie on a D-brane?

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions, branes

In the second edition of professor Zwiebach's book "A First Course in String Theory", on page 331, on the 3rd line of section 15.1, it says

> "In the presence of a D-brane, the endpoints of open strings must lie on the brane."

But if there are two or more parallel D-branes present, then since an endpoint can only lie on one of them, it will fail to lie on any of the others. There are figures in the book that depict the presence of multiple parallel D-branes and of course, there are strings whose endpoints fail to lie on all of them. Have I misinterpreted his meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have I misinterpreted his meaning?

Yes. What Zwiebach means is that the endpoints of open strings must lie on **some** brane. But the brane doesn't have to be the same for both endpoints.

Comment: I will mark this as an erratum. It should read "In the presence of D-branes, the endpoints of open strings must lie on them."

Comment: Mark also the answer as accepted, assuming it is all you needed. Cheers